# Powershell AWS create a security group assigning a prefixlist

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to find a way in powershell to create a prefixlist and security group and attach the prefixlist to the Security Group but coming across a type error and not fully sure how i would pass in the prefixlist.

Creating the preflixlist.

```
$Prefix = New-EC2ManagedPrefixList -PrefixListName "PrefixListTest1" -AddressFamily IPV4 -MaxEntry 2 -Entry @{cidr='10.0.0.0/27'}
```

Then trying to create an SG and assign that prefix list to it.

```
    $NewGroup = @{
        GroupName   = ""PrefixList-SG"
        Description = "PrefixList-SG"
        VpcId       = $vpc.id
        Force       = $true
        Region      = $vpc.region
    }
    $newGroup = New-EC2SecurityGroup @NewGroup
    Grant-EC2SecurityGroupIngress -GroupId  $newGroup -IpPermission @{IpProtocol = "udp" ; FromPort = "138"   ; ToPort = "138"  ; PrefixListIds= $Prefix }
```

But in doing so i'm getting the error "Grant-EC2SecurityGroupIngress : Cannot bind parameter 'IpPermission'. Cannot create object of type "Amazon.EC2.Model.IpPermission". Cannot convert the "pl-aaeebbccdd990" value of type "System.String" to type "Amazon.EC2.Model.PrefixListId"."

As far as I can tell, the grant-EC2SecurityGroupIngress parameter "-IpPermission <IpPermission[]>" accepts PrefixListIds, but that doesn't seem to allow a prefixlistid from one that was just created?

Comment: `GroupName   = ""PrefixList-SG"` has one double-quote too many. Is that a typo when posting?

Comment: It is a typo just checked, fails after the new Group creation anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was aable to accomplish this by creating the prefixlist using:

```
$managedPrefixList        = New-EC2ManagedPrefixList -PrefixListName "PrefixListTest1" -AddressFamily IPV4 -MaxEntry 2 -Entry @{cidr = "10.0.0.0/27" }
$prefixListId             = [Amazon.EC2.Model.PrefixListId]::new()
$prefixListId.Description = $managedPrefixList.PrefixListName
$prefixListId.Id          = $managedPrefixList.PrefixListId
```

Then i passed in the prefix list like so:

```
Grant-EC2SecurityGroupIngress -GroupId  $newGroup -IpPermission @{ IpProtocol = "udp"; FromPort = "138"; ToPort = "138"; PrefixListIds = $prefixListId }
```